# Combinations: How many of the possible answer sequences have the correct answer to precisely 5 questions?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

A quiz consists of ten True/False questions. Each question is answered with
either True or False (no question is left blank).
How do I get the possible answer sequences have the correct answer to precisely 5 questions? 
I've only thought of ${10 \choose 2} - {10 \choose 5}$. But I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it.

Comment: What were your thoughts ?

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I've came up with subtracting the 5 questions from the total outcomes to get the answer.

Comment: @christinaqwer Why?  You just want to count the ways to select correct answers.  ( Also $^{10}C_2$ is *not* the count of total outcomes. )

Comment: So it will just be ${10 \choose 5}$? Or am I on the wrong track

Comment: Also,is the total ${20 \choose 10}$?

Comment: The total is $2^{10}$.  Ten questions with a choice or two answers each.

Answer (score 1):

An answer is either correct or incorrect, since no question goes unanswered.   It's binary.

So just count how many ways there are to: select $5$ of the $10$ questions to have their correct answer and give all the other questions their incorrect answer.

Comment: so my answer would just be ${10 \choose 5}$

Comment: Yes.  That is correct, @christinaqwer